# Error: Unpack requires a bytes object of length 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial

Добрый день, читаю данные по Modbus и при конвертации следующая ошибка: Unpack requires a bytes object of length 4 . Не могу найти решение. Спасибо.

```
from  pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
import serial.rs485
import time
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadBuilder
from pymodbus.compat import iteritems
import threading
import gc

client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='COM2', timeout=0.5, baudrate=19200)
client.connect()
rs485_mode = serial.rs485.RS485Settings(delay_before_tx = 0, delay_before_rx = 0, rts_level_for_tx=True, rts_level_for_rx=False, loopback=False)
#client.socket.rs485_mode = rs485_mode
builder = BinaryPayloadBuilder(endian=Endian.Big)
print('connected')
values_for_transmit =[]
def getModbus():
  while True:
   try:
    rr = client.read_holding_registers(0x00 ,6,unit=1)
    decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(rr.registers, endian=Endian.Little)


    arr = [rr.registers[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(rr.registers), 2)]
    print(arr)

    for x in arr:
        decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(x, endian=Endian.Little)
        print(decoder.decode_32bit_float())
        values_for_transmit[arr.index(x)] = decoder.decode_32bit_float()
        print(values_for_transmit)
   except Exception as e:
    print(e)

   time.sleep(1)
   gc.collect()


if __name__ == "__main__":
 try:
  modb = threading.Thread(target=getModbus())
  modb.daemon = True
  modb.start()

 except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

Comment: В какой строчке ошибка? Добавьте tracedack

Comment: Добрый день! Прошу прощения за поздний ответ. Заменил в цикле for код на следующий:
         packed_string = struct.pack("HH", *t)
         unpacked_float = struct.unpack("f", packed_string)[0]
          print(unpacked_float)
          print(arr.index(x))

          values_for_transmit[(arr.index(x))]= unpacked_float